# How to combine ColdFusion Query and XML?

Tags: xml, coldfusion

I'm working on project where I have to combine coldfusion query and xml output. Everytime I try to run my page I'm getting this error:

```
An Error Occurred
XML Parser Returned Error: Invalid document end (5)
Source Path: http://test/apps/Milos/staffsearch.cfm
Call Type: http
View XML
```

If I save my page as .cfm file page runs fine but I want that page to be .xml file. Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cfquery name="myQuery" datasource="Test">
    Select StaffId,FirstName,LastName
    From Staff
</cfquery>
<!-- These are standard elements which can be inserted back into a request -->
<cfoutput query="myQuery">
<livelookup version="1.0" columns="first_name,last_name">
    <customer>
        <customer_id>#XMLFormat(StaffId)#</customer_id>
        <first_name>#XMLFormat(FirstName)#</first_name>
        <last_name>#XMLFormat(LastName)#</last_name>
    </customer>
</livelookup>
</cfoutput>
```

Here is my XML:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
   <!-- These are standard elements which can be inserted back into a request -->
   <livelookup version="1.0" columns="first_name,last_name">
        <customer>
            <customer_id>6</customer_id>
            <first_name>Jon</first_name>
            <last_name>Cook</last_name>
        </customer>
        <customer>
            <customer_id>7</customer_id>
            <first_name>Dave</first_name>
            <last_name>Herman</last_name>
        </customer>
    </livelookup>
```

Comment: Removing the query has the same result, right? or did you skip the step of creating a minimal example.

Comment: I did not try to remove the query.

Comment: shouldn't your cfoutput wrap the whole <customer></customer> element? otherwise you're going to have one customer with multiple customer_id elements. **this however won't fix your problem**

Comment: I tried to wrap the whole <customer> but that did not change anything.

Comment: Your problem looks like a hidden character problem to me. I don't however see any hidden characters in the posted code. I would need to see the generated xml instead. (which is why removing the query could be useful.)

Comment: @user3023588 - I do not mean this sarcastically, but when posting a question, it helps to think about what information someone else might need if they were trying to answer it :)  For example, if you are getting an xml parsing error, well ... others will need to see the actual XML generated AND the code trying to parse it (assuming it is not external service).  Without the relevant information we can only guess. Creating a [small, *stand-alone*, example](http://www.sscce.org/), that can be run in any environment should be part of the troubleshooting process.

Comment: If I'm enough familiar with XML I wouldn't ask any question.

Comment: Try and get a working XML example **without** using ColdFusion, then write your ColdFusion code to replicate the format of your example. @Leigh makes a great point that you need to include more information to get a reasonable answer.

Comment: I updated my question. Here is my code and my XML output. I'm still getting an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an XML document, there should only be one parent node. You are duplicating the `<livelookup>` node in your XML document, which is leading to a syntax error.

My changing where your `cfoutput` is located, you can output multiple `<customer>` nodes in the `<livelookup>` parent node (as per the livelookup spec [here](https://support.helpspot.com/index.php?pg=kb.page&id=6))

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><cfsilent>
<cfquery name="myQuery" datasource="Test">
    SELECT  StaffId,FirstName,LastName
    FROM    Staff
</cfquery>
<!--- These are standard elements which can be inserted back into a request --->
</cfsilent>
<livelookup version="1.0" columns="first_name,last_name">
<cfoutput query="myQuery"><customer>
    <customer_id>#XMLFormat(StaffId)#</customer_id>
    <first_name>#XMLFormat(FirstName)#</first_name>
    <last_name>#XMLFormat(LastName)#</last_name>
</customer></cfoutput>
</livelookup>
```

This will produce the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<livelookup version="1.0" columns="first_name,last_name">
    <customer>
        <customer_id>6</customer_id>
        <first_name>Dave</first_name>
        <last_name>Cook</last_name>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <customer_id>7</customer_id>
        <first_name>Jon</first_name>
        <last_name>Maiden</last_name>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <customer_id>94</customer_id>
        <first_name>Ian</first_name>
        <last_name>Hart</last_name>
    </customer>
</livelookup>
```

Example using CF's xml functions will produce the same output:

```
<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="true"  />
<cfheader name="Content-Type" value="text/xml">

<cfset xmlObj = xmlNew() />
<cfset xmlObj.livelookup = xmlElemNew( xmlObj, 'livelookup' ) />
<cfset xmlObj.livelookup.xmlAttributes['version'] = '1.0' />
<cfset xmlObj.livelookup.xmlAttributes['columns'] = 'first_name,last_name' />

<cfloop query="myQuery">
    <cfset xmlObj.livelookup.xmlChildren[currentRow] = xmlElemNew( xmlObj, 'customer' )>

    <cfset xmlObj.livelookup.xmlChildren[currentRow]['customer_id'] = xmlElemNew( xmlObj, 'customer_id' )>
    <cfset xmlObj.livelookup.xmlChildren[currentRow]['customer_id'].xmlText = myQuery.StaffId>

    <cfset xmlObj.livelookup.xmlChildren[currentRow]['first_name'] = xmlElemNew( xmlObj, 'first_name' )>
    <cfset xmlObj.livelookup.xmlChildren[currentRow]['first_name'].xmlText = myQuery.firstName>

    <cfset xmlObj.livelookup.xmlChildren[currentRow]['last_name'] = xmlElemNew( xmlObj, 'last_name' )>
    <cfset xmlObj.livelookup.xmlChildren[currentRow]['last_name'].xmlText = myQuery.lastName>
</cfloop>

<cfoutput>#toString(xmlObj)#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding you were right about that, but there is one more thing, space in between each customer record causing the problem. Do you know how to get rid of that blank space in between them? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've updated my answer to remove white space using `cfsilent`. You could also use `<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="true" />`

Comment: Where I should place <cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="true" /> because <cfsilent> does not work for me?

Comment: I tweaked the answer again. I didn't get rid of all the white space. Please be more specific. Instead of saying "<cfsilent> does not work for me", say **why** or **how** it doesn't work.

Comment: Does not reduce the space in between <customer></customer> tags. That cause problem for me. I want all of them without any space in between. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm still not getting my XML same as yours in this answer. Mine is like you can see in updated question above.

Comment: *That cause problem for me* Why do think that is the problem? A bigger problem is you are missing the closing `</livelookup>` tag.  Add that to your current string and it parses just fine with XMLParse. That raises the question, exactly what is being used to parse the XML? As an aside, while it is technically possible to use a .cfm file to generate xml, controlling output and whitespace is a lot easier if you use cfsavecontent and a CFC, rather than outputting directly within a .cfm file.

Comment: @beloitdavisja - Though technically it may work, it is cleaner to separate query and xml generation code ie do not nest cfquery's within the xml IMO :)

Comment: Oh I agree. If it were me, I'd have a DAO object that gets all the queries, and another object that builds the XML structure, but I'm trying to keep it simple and not write a whole library for a simple question...

Comment: Agreed.  Clear and simple is best for S.O. The reason for mentioning query placement is that you often see new users mixing queries and output, mistakenly believing it is required, when it is not and just makes code harder to read.  Separating things out in basic example is a subtle way to encourage better practices ;-). Plus it makes the example clearer and easier to understand. Granted, I do not know anything about the asker's background, so they may already be aware of this.

Comment: Can anyone provide example of how I can separate query and XML in different files? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user3023588 - 1) First, the XML you posted parses find with CF's xmlParse function once you add the closing `</livelookup>` tag.  Did you create a hard coded example with that *exact* xml to see if parses? 2) You never told us what code are you using the parse the XML. Are you using CF or something else?

Comment: I updated my question. This is how my output looks like after I run my .cfm page. I use cold fusion query to get XML output above. I tried to use that hard coded example that I got and put in separate .xml file. After I used that my Live Lookup works fine. But if I use my .cfm page in that case I'm getting error as you can see above.

Comment: What code/application is throwing that error? As I mentioned, the xml in the above answer parses successfully with the xmlParse() function (CF11), which suggests you are using something different.  We have asked three times, but you still have not told us what that is yet :P Side note, you should probably add a header to the page, indicating the response contains xml rather than text/html ie `<cfheader name="Content-Type" value="text/xml">`.

Comment: @user3023588 If you're having so much trouble with the xml formatting that you're formatting yourself, you should probably consider using ColdFusion's xml functions to build and and handle output the xml object. I've included an example in the answer.

Comment: I formatted XML output how I wanted actually but my issue now is to separate coldfusion query on the one .cfm page and xml code to another .xml page if that's even possible?